# Validation error for datefield in django

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker

I have used jQuery datepicker to select dates.

Inside the template's script tag.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#id_birthday" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $('#id_birthday').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
});
```

Inside the template's form tag.

```
{{ form.birthday }}
```

Inside my models.py

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

Inside my forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    birthday = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%Y-%m-%d'), input_formats=('%Y-%m-%d',))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfiles
        fields = ('email', 'location', 'birthday', 'name')
```

I'm getting

> ValidationError [u'Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

Also when I select a date using the picker it shows it as mm/dd/yyyy. Is my jQuery code also wrong?

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using two different date formats. Have you tried to use `%Y-%m-%d` instead in `forms.py`?

Comment: that was a typo error when i wrote the code in SC. Corrected it.

Comment: sorry. corrected it now. but still failing.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. The problem was with the Java script code.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#id_birthday" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Solved the problem.